# How do I make the circle div in the center change color from yellow to white and vice versa on every click inside the circle?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So far I have managed to do this on single click.

[I removed the lightbulb image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8TqP.png)

```
const div = document.getElementById("sphere");

div.addEventListener("click", e => {
    console.log("You clicked the mouse!");
    div.style.backgroundColor = "white";
})
```

How do I make the circle div in the center change color from yellow to white and vice versa on every click inside the circle?

Comment: Is the colour a part of the image? Is the image an SVG? Please add a [mcve] _including the image_

Comment: share your HTML as well :)

Comment: I've just updated the image to make it clearer.

Comment: @nosTa <body>
    <div id="sphere">
    </div>
    <script src="scripts.js">
    </script>
</body>

Comment: @JoonMoon please update the code, not the image.

Comment: you always apply the `backgroundColor` white. You can use a `ternary conditional operator` such as: `div.style.backgroundColor = (div.style.backgroundColor === 'white') ? 'yellow' : 'white'` or use `classList.toggle` and add changes through CSS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just try this way:

```js
 const div = document.getElementById("sphere");

      div.addEventListener("click", e => {
        console.log("You clicked the mouse!");
        div.classList.toggle('active')
      })
```

```css
#sphere {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: yellow;
      }

      img {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding-top: 20px;
      }

      #sphere.active {
        background-color: white;
      }
```

```html
<div id="sphere">
      <img src="https://freepngimg.com/thumb/bulb/31669-1-bulb-off-transparent-image.png">
    </div>
```

Comment: I just tried it thanks a lot! :)

Comment: While this answers the question you should not give answers with `try this`. You should always add a sufficient explanation of what you did and how you solve something. A user that does not know what you did can not reproduce it or learn from it. without explanation. A user that knows what you did and knows how to do it, would not need to ask the question in the first palce.

Answer (score -1):

I would create one css class white (background white) and one yellow (background yellow). Then with js you just add or remove the class you want.

Or you can make it white by default and just create a yellow background class, then you use js toggle class which add or remove automatically a class https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp

Hope it helps

Comment: instead of add and remove you should simply toggle. However I find you answer unspecific and lacking demonstrations. It is IMHO only a little more then a link.

Comment: You are always free to edit your answer to meet the guidelines such as [answer]. Add a sufficient example as validation. It also adds value in form for better readability, specificity, and adding specific context examples for further readers. As of now I think that your answer is barely enough to be not a NAA but insufficient as a quality answer and as such deserve a down-vote,

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll try do that in the future. What is NAA?

Comment: NAA = Not an answer (Answer that does not attempt to answer a question or is barely more then a link)

Answer (score -1):

To do this without toggling classes you can create a variable to keep track of which color is being displayed. Something like this:

```
const div = document.getElementById("sphere");
let isWhite = false;

div.addEventListener("click", e => {
    console.log("You clicked the mouse!");
    div.style.backgroundColor = isWhite ? "white" : "yellow";
    isWhite = !isWhite;
})
```

Comment: While I don't think that you deserve a down-vote for you answer it is lacking simplicity for a denary conditional operator. You don't need an extra variable, you just need to check if that `backgrounColor` is already applied or not.